# Unable to insert a Table using HTML in blog page on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, html

I am relentlessly trying to insert a simple HTML table into my blog page (not post, but a new secondary page I created) on Tumblr. Each time I put in the code, the text appears unformatted on the screen and when I switch back and forth between "edit html" mode, it changes the table into a paragraph tag automatically and I just don't understand why this is happening.

How can I enter a simple HTML table in a Tumblr page? To add any content or html code, it gives me a text editor with the ability to modify the html code for the added content. So that's where I am inserting the code, in the edit-HTML mode.

Note: Tumblr allows users to switch between Standard, Custom Layouts and Redirects. I need to work with the Standard Layout and as I need the rest of the theme but just need to be able to organize content in a table in the space reserved for the blog post.

Sample code:

```
<div id="divTable">
<table id="contentTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Counts</th>
        <th>Selection</th>
        <th>Document</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pages</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Words</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Characters (no spaces)</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Characters (with spaces)</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I intend to edit the CSS for this table later in the main style sheet in the Tumblr theme I am working with.

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch the default text editor being used to adjust the HTML code from Rich Text to Plain Text/HTML in Account → Preferences → Text-editor.

The rich text editor apparently changes some of the tags such as `<embed>`, `<table>` etc to `<p>` tags automatically.

The plain text editor comes with HTML editing enabled by default.